# Constructing fundamental neighborhood for composition of covering maps

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, covering-spaces

I'm working on problem IX.7.1 of Conway's *Functions of a Complex Variable*:

> If $(X,\rho)$ is a covering space of $\Omega$ and $(\Omega, \pi)$ is a covering space of $Y$, prove that $(X,\pi\circ\rho)$ is a covering space of $Y$.

This is how I've gone about the problem:  If $y \in Y$, there is some neighborhood $\Delta _y$ such that (calling $\{c_i\}_{I \in \mathcal{A}}$ the components of $\pi^{-1}(\Delta_y)$ in $\Omega$) each $c_i$ is open in $\Omega$ and $\pi:c_i \to \pi(c_i) = \Delta_y$ is a homeomorphism (calling this a *fundamental neighborhood*).

We can do the same thing for each preimage of $y$ under $\pi$ in $\Omega$, constructing a fundamental neighborhood for each w.r.t. the map $\rho: X \to \Omega$.

So the way that I've tried to construct a fundamental neighborhood about $y$ for the mapping $\pi \circ \rho$ is by intersecting the fundamental neighborhoods of each preimage of $y$ under $\pi$ with the the components $c_i$ (call these intersections $B_i$).  Each of these intersections is a single intersection of open sets, so open.  Then, take the fundamental neighborhood of $y$ w.r.t the map $\pi \circ \rho$ to be the intersection of each $\pi(B_i)$.

The problem that I'm having is that this is an arbitrary intersection of open sets, so this may not be open; further, I don't see how we can just take the interior, since the intersection may just be a singleton.  Any ideas on how to ensure this results in an open set?

Thanks!

Comment: $\pi$ must have finite fibres for the composition to be a covering map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is composition of covering maps covering map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989083/is-composition-of-covering-maps-covering-map)

Comment: In general $\rho \circ \pi : X \to Y$ is not a covering. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989083.