# A non-example of covering of the 1-circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've found this assertion ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3021v2.pdf) , pag 5) about covering spaces: the map $p\colon\mathbb{S}^{1}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{S}^{1}$
given by $\left(z,n\right)\mapsto z^{n}$ is NOT a covering map of
the 1-sphere (on $\mathbb{N}$ the discrete topology, as usual).

Well, to show it I should prove that each point of the 1-sphere doesn't
admit any fundamental neighborhood. For example take the point $1=e^{2i\pi}$
and a small connected neighborhood $U$ of this point. The preimage
of $U$ is clearly a disjoint union of open connected sets of the
form $U_{j}\times\left\{ j\right\} $ where $U_{j}$ contains an n-th
root of 1. But it seems also clear that $U_{j}\times\left\{ j\right\} $
is homeomorphic through $p$ to the initial set $U$. This is exactely
the proof to show that the point admits a fundamental neighborhood.
Where is the mistake?

It should also be remarked that $p\colon\mathbb{S}^{1}\times\left\{ 1,...n\right\} \to\mathbb{S}^{1}$
defined in the same way is a covering since it has finite fiber, so
somewhere I should exploit the fact that the fiber is infinite.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below the map actually seems to be a covering. Although sometimes people will include connectedness as a prerequisite for a covering map. This might be why the article states that it is not a covering map.

Answer (score 2):

I think $p$ is a covering.

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to S^1, \varphi(t) = e^{it}$. The set $U = \varphi((-\pi,\pi)) = S^1 \backslash \{ -1 \}$ is an open neighborhood of $1$ in $S^1$. We have $p^{-1}(U) \cap S^1 \times \{ n \} = \bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} U(k,n) \times \{ n \} $ where $U(k,n) = \varphi((\frac{2\pi k}{n} - \frac{\pi}{n},\frac{2\pi k}{n} + \frac{\pi}{n}))$. The intervals $J(k,n) = (\frac{2\pi k}{n} - \frac{\pi}{n},\frac{2\pi k}{n} + \frac{\pi}{n})$ are pairwise disjoint and contained in $(-\frac{\pi}{n}, \frac{2\pi (n-1)}{n} + \frac{\pi}{n}) = (-\frac{\pi}{n}, 2\pi - \frac{\pi}{n})$. This shows that also the $U(k,n)$ are pairwise disjoint. In fact, the $U(k,n)$ are the components of $S^1 \backslash \{ \eta_1, .... \eta_n \}$, where the $\eta_k$ are the $n$-th complex roots of $-1$.

Each $U(k,n) \times \{ n \}$ is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$. Therefore $U$ is evenly covered. A similar argument works for $V = \varphi((0,2\pi)) =  S^1 \backslash \{ 1 \}$.

Comment: I think $p$ is a covering too (I had essentially the same idea of you). What makes me doubt is that the author says "one easily sees it is NOT".

Comment: Any sequence of coverings $p_n : X_n \to X$ produces a continuous $p : \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n \times \{ n \} \to X$. I think in general it will be no covering because we will not able to find a neighborhood $U$ of a point $x$ which is evenly covered by **all** $p_n$. I don't know an example, but the above map $p$ is certainly not.

Comment: Jeremy Brazas (the author of the article you quoted in your question) has answered https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989083. The example of a semicovering map which as not a covering map presented there is a different one than the above map $p$.